# Xcode Autocomplete is not working in particular project but it works in other projects

Tags: swift, xcode, ide

After a particular commit in my project, Xcode stopped using autocompletion while in another project it's working fine.

Comment: Did you try clearing derived data and restarting Xcode ? Happens to me all the time

Comment: I have tried this several times but still not able to fix this

Comment: In the Preferences window, navigate to Text Editing Preferences and check if "Suggest completion while typing" is checked or not.